# How to surpress pagenumbers in bibliography section in LyX?

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, back-referencing

If you look at this picture

[image]

you can see, that LyX generated the pagenumber where I cited book [2].

How can I surpress that behaviour?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can see which packages you are using etc.  One cause may be that `hyperef` is loaded with the `backref` option.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Your answer guided me towards the correct direction, thanks! I figured out the solution and posted it as an answer. Feel free to edit if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had to deactivate backreferences in

```
-> Document settings
   -> PDF-Settings
      -> Hyperlinks
         -> Backreferences
            Select "Off" in Drop-Down-Menu
```

I don't know the exact english words for every single entry above. See screenshot for a possible better clarification.

[image]

Comment: Glad my suggestion helped.  Your translations look good, but I don't have LyX installed on my system, so may be someone who does can check them.